# how to disable mod_jk log completely?

Tags: tomcat, logging, mod-jk

My mod_jk.log gets 2MB bigger in an hour and all it has entries like :

```
[Mon Aug 13 10:51:28 2012] ajp13 www.my_site.com 0.690152
[Mon Aug 13 10:51:28 2012] ajp13 www.my_site.com 0.002675
[Mon Aug 13 10:51:29 2012] ajp13 www.my_site.com 0.000794
[Mon Aug 13 10:51:30 2012] ajp13 www.my_site.com 0.001993
[Mon Aug 13 10:51:30 2012] ajp13 www.my_site.com 0.000764
[Mon Aug 13 10:51:35 2012] ajp13 www.my_site.com 0.004724
```

So, how can I disable this logging completely?

Currently I have set logLevel to info in configuration file. Apache tomcat doc suggests, error/debug/info are only valid option.

Please help.

Also how can I rotate log after one day? Currently it's being rotated after week by default (I did not write/change anything for that).

Thanks.

Comment: Setting log level to error might decrease log size. I you really want to disable it, you can try `JkLogFile     /dev/null`. Changing how log files are rotated might depend on your os (if you installed modjk from packages). Can you provide information about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, how can I disable this logging completely?

Point it to `/dev/null`:

```
JkLogFile           /dev/null
JkLogLevel          info
```

> Also how can I rotate log after one day? Currently it's being rotated
>   after week by default (I did not write/change anything for that).

Add a `daily` directive to the `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd`:

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    daily
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /sbin/service httpd reload > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```